# How to resolve signalR connection limit

Tags: asp.net, local-storage, signalr

I have a web application where hundreds of clients use it. Each client has a server, either on-premises or in the cloud. Each client can have multiple users connected at the same time to the server.

I'm implementing a functionality where it should be possible for a user to request a request "remotely" for X number of users also logged in at the same time.

I'm using SignalR to make all users stay connected at the same time waiting for messages from remote requests and also able to respond to them, assuming that in this case each user is on a different machine.

In this scenario, each user who logs into the system needs to "initialize the connection" with signalR to "listen" for new messages or to be able to send them when necessary. However, I have had a problem with this, because after a few connections with SignalR the page simply keeps loading and only actually loads after closing one of the open browser tabs or one of the other users ending the connection either by closing the browser or the open tab that opened the connection.

I solved half of the problem, which was "not opening" a new connection every browser tab opened, using IWC-SignalR which is based on localstorage.

The other half of the problem is that if different users access on different machines I can't control it via localstorage.

Is there any way to open a single signalr connection and share that connection with different users?

Comment: We’ll need a bit more information about the system. SignalR by itself has no limits. Web server might have. There are systems with thousands of connections at the same time without problems. So what’s “a few connections” that causes issues? Which .NET/SignalR version? Which server is running the system?

Comment: SignalR has a limit which is 10k for cpu core. But it also has scalelibility options like redis, sql server etc.

Comment: .NET versao 4.6.1, 
ASP.NET SignalR 2.4.3,
I use the Internet Information Services (IIS) version 10.0.22000.739

Comment: how to increase the limit of IIS?